# SQL which OR condition matched scoring

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement where I am self joining a table eg Employee and I have condition which says First Name matches plus any three of columns either Last Name matched Or date of birth or email or phone or city or country matches so first name has to match and then any of the three columns mentioned matches, how can I do this I sql?

SQL would be something like:

```
where c1.firstname=c2.firstname
and ( c1.lastname = c2.lastname or c1.dob = c2.dob or ....)
```

I am having hard time enforcing the requirement that any 3 attributes match

Comment: Your approach is ok. Put brackets around individual conditions.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or Oracle?  Only tag with the products you are really using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should be doing the comparison in the *on* clause, not the `where` clause.

Second, you can count the matches:

```
select c1.*, c2.*
from c c1 join
     c c2
     on c1.firstname = c2.firstname and
        ((case when c1.lastname = c2.lastname then 1 else 0 end) + 
         (case when c1.dob = c2.dob then 1 else 0 end) + 
         (case when c1.email = c2.email then 1 else 0 end) + 
         (case when c1.phone = c2.phone then 1 else 0 end) + 
         (case when c1.city = c2.city then 1 else 0 end) + 
         (case when c1.country = c2.country then 1 else 0 end)
        ) >= 3;
```

Third, be careful about the matches.  If `city` matches, then `country` probably also matches -- and a lot of people can have the same first name in the same city.

Answer (score 4):

You can replace the `OR` with a sum of conditionals that add `1` for each match, count the number of matches, and filter on the total:

```
where c1.firstname=c2.firstname and
    (case when c1.lastname = c2.lastname then 1 else 0 end
    +case when c1.dob = c2.dob then 1 else 0 end
    +case when c1.addr1 = c2.addr1 then 1 else 0 end
    +case when c1.addr2 = c2.addr2 then 1 else 0 end
    +case when c1.phone = c2.phone then 1 else 0 end) >= 3
```